# In TF2 do strange parts move the other strange parts down on your weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm afraid that if I apply multiple strange parts to my strange minigun that they'll be moved down after I apply the other parts and it will look bad.

Example: I apply the dominations part. I then add the critical kills part. Will my minigun appear as so or the other way around (it'll be added below the previous part).

```
                           Strange Minigun
                                0 kills
                          Critical Kills: 0   
                           DOminations: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Backpack I have a [Strange Degreaser](http://www.tf2items.com/item/2289941618). 
For that Degreaser, I traded/bought the Strange Parts Posthumous Kills, Projectiles Reflected and Allies Extinguished in that order.

I bought and installed those Parts in said order, and according to my inventory, the parts appear in the order I installed them, so the new Strange Part should appear under the previously installed parts.

Comment: It seems tf2items doesn't display strange part attachments. The backpack icons in your Steam inventory page are clickable links - you can use those to link to your items (provided their item IDs don't change). [Here's your Degreaser.](http://steamcommunity.com/id/private_meta/inventory/#440_2_2289941618)

Comment: Ah yes, the browser link itself doesn't change, and I didn't see a link to the item itself, didn't think of copying source link of the item on the left side.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a hidden feature :)

Comment: I used it already quite some time ago and forgot how to use it, so I just used tf2items :D